# Spring MVC Controller List<MyClass> as a parameter

Tags: spring, list, model-view-controller, parameters, controller

I have a Spring MVC application. Jsp page contains form, which submitting.
My controller's method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "photos/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String fileDetailsUpload(List<PhotoDTO> photoDTO,
                                    BindingResult bindingResult,
                                   HttpServletRequest request) {
        // in the point **photoDTO** is null
    }
```

My class is:

```
    public class PhotoDTO {
        private Boolean mainPhoto;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private Long realtyId;

//getters/setters
```

But, if I write the same method, but param is just my object:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "photos/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String fileDetailsUpload(PhotoDTO photoDTO,
                                        BindingResult bindingResult,
                                        HttpServletRequest request) {
// Everething is Ok **photoDTO** has all fields, which were fielded on the JSP
```

What should I do in the situation? What if I have on Jsp many **PhotoDTO** objects (15) how can I recive all of them on the server part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page should pass the parameters for each `PhotoDTO` in the list back to the server in the appropriate format.  In this case you need to use the status var to specify the index of each object in the list using the name attribute.

```
<form>
<c:forEach items="${photoDTO}" var="photo" varStatus="status">
        <input name="photoDTO[${status.index}].title" value="${photo.title}"/>
        <input name="photoDTO[${status.index}].description" value="${photo.description}"/>
</c:forEach>
</form>
```

Comment: Anyway to do it in plain html using client side scripts rather than using JSTL. I need to dynamically add columns on client. What I need to know is what should I pass as `name` attribute of input objects in order to have them as list in controller argument.